# How do you make sure Java finds your variable across methods?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to write a Java class where the main method creates an array to store 30 integers. Afterwards, I call a method called LOAD() in the main method, whose job is to populate the array with 30 integers from 1-300.

I have written what I think is a complete Java class to do this, yet the compiler keeps telling me this error of that it `cannot find the symbol` for symbol randomThirty, my array variable's name.

Here is my code so far, yet I am not sure why my randomThirty is not being picked up by LOAD(), perhaps I need to pass the parameters explicitly in the parens of LOAD?

```
import java.util.*;

public class arrayNums
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
     //main method which creates an array to store 30 integers

    int[] randomThirty = new int[30]; //declare and set the array randomThirty to have 30 elements as int type

    System.out.println("Here are 30 random numbers: " + randomThirty);

LOAD(); // the job of this method is to populate this array with 30 integers in the range of 1 through 300.
}


public static void LOAD()
{
    // looping through to assign random values from 1 - 300
    for (int i = 0; i < randomThirty.length(); i++) {
        randomThirty[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 301); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in your comment:

```
LOAD(); // the job of this method is to populate this array
```

So you've got an array that you want the method to work with... you should pass it to the method:

```
load(randomThirty);

// Method declaration change...
public static void load(int[] arrayToFill)
```

That's a good approach when a method isn't *naturally* in the context where it has access to state. In this case is looks like the appropriate approach. For other situations, you could use a static or instance variable, depending on the context.

(You should look at the `Random` class, by the way - and learn about Java naming conventions.)

Comment: That makes sense, though when I put the randomThirty as a parameter for LOAD(); I still got this error at randomThirty.length() for the length() method. So I took out the parens at length() and that error went away, not sure why really. However, once I compiled and ran it then, the System.out.println() call to test the array now comes with this cryptic output:     Here are 30 random numbers: [I@12dacd1  ...why's that? Isn't it supposed to output the array's contents (should be 30 elements of random value from 1-300).

Comment: @artemd: There isn't a length method. There's an accessible length *field* on arrays. And no, calling `toString` on an array doesn't get you the content, because the array type doesn't override `toString`. Call `Arrays.toString(array)` instead.

Comment: Ok, I get the terminology for fields there Jon Skeet. When I use the toString call, the array returned as a string is 30 values, but they're not random, just a bunch of 0s...Is there something wrong with my for loop? Or is my random just not random enough? I ran it several times, yet it keeps returning just a bunch of 0s.

Comment: @artemd: Well having fixed up your code, it works for me - so I suggest you edit your question to show what you've got now.

Comment: Ok, I'll just ask about the 0s in another question.

Comment: My question was answered here by aix, I was calling LOAD after I actually printed out to the screen with System.out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743904/array-to-generate-30-random-numbers-from-1-300-returns-all-0s-instead-of-other-nu

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass `randomThirty` into your load method, or make it a static variable on the class (i.e. move it out of the method).

So you could do

`LOAD(randomThirty); // pass the reference in`

and change your method definition to

`public static void LOAD(int[] randomThirty) {...}`

or you can make `randomThirty` a static property on the class

```
public class arrayNums {
    // will be available anywhere in the class; you don't need to pass it around
    private static int [] RANDOM_THIRTY = new int[30]; // instantiate here
    ...

    public static void main(String args[]) { ... } // calls load
    ...
    public static void load(){...}
    ...
}
```

as a note, java conventions are that class names are like `ArrayNums` and method names should be like `load` or `loadNums`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass your array as a param , cuz it's out of the load method's scope .

```
LOAD(randomThirty);




public static void LOAD(int[] randomThirty)
    {
        // looping through to assign random values from 1 - 300
        for (int i = 0; i < randomThirty.length(); i++) {
            randomThirty[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 301); 
    }
```