# Array to generate 30 random numbers from 1-300 returns all 0s instead of other numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have a problem where I'm trying to fill an array with 30 random integers from the range 1-300 with just a main method and one more method called LOAD(). For some reason my code below generates an array with my test statement `System.out.println("Here are 30 random numbers: " + Arrays.toString(randomThirty));` but it's filled with only 0s and no other numbers in all fields.

```
import java.util.*;

public class randArray
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
     //main method which creates an array to store 30 integers

    int[] randomThirty = new int[30]; //declare and set the array randomThirty to have 30 elements as int type

    System.out.println("Here are 30 random numbers: " + Arrays.toString(randomThirty));

    LOAD(randomThirty); // the job of this method is to populate this array with 30 integers in the range of 1 through 300.

}

public static void LOAD(int[] randomThirty)
{
    // looping through to assign random values from 1 - 300
    for (int i = 0; i < randomThirty.length; i++) {
        randomThirty[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 301); 
}
}
```

}

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range

Comment: Thanks hvgotcodes, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that you print out the array first, and populate it second.

In other words, `LOAD()` doesn't get called until **after** you've printed out the array.

Comment: Heh, silly mistake there. So order matters in Java like this? Thanks aix.

Answer (score 1):

u are printing before calling the method....change the order of calling and it will work